# What is E(Y|X=x), X~Pos(λ) and Y | {X=x} ~ Poi(x), x in |R?

Tags: probability

I know the defintion of E(Y|X=x), but how can I get P(Y=y,X=x) ? Or is that a wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y \mid X=x \sim \text{Pois}(x)$, then your expectation is just $x$, the expectation of a $\text{Pois}(x)$-distributed random variable. Since you are conditioning on $X$ taking a specific value $x$.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Is there a way to get that result using the definition of E(Y|X=x) ?

Comment: @dadadudududa If $Y\mid X{=}x\sim\mathcal{Pois}(x)$ then $\mathsf P(Y{=}y\mid X{=}x)= \dfrac{x^{-y}\mathrm e^{-x}}{y!}\mathbf 1_{y\in\Bbb N}$. ...